# Fourier Transform on Sobolev Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

The Sobolev spaces are defined for $ 1\leq p < \infty$, as follows
    $$ W^{1,p} := \left\{ u\in L^p(\mathbb{R}) \,\Big\vert \exists \, g\in L^p(\mathbb{R}) \mbox{ such that } \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u\varphi' = - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g\varphi ,\, \forall \varphi \in C^{1}_c(\mathbb{R}). \right\}
 $$

If we consider the Fourier transform
    \begin{equation}
 \mathcal{F}_p(f)(s):=\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-isx} f(x)\,dx \qquad (s\in \mathbb{R})
 \end{equation}
Then it is known that $\mathcal{F}_p(f)$ belongs to $L^q(\mathbb{R})$ for $1<p<2$ and $1/p + 1/q =1$.

I wonder know if there is something else we can say about the image of $W^{1,p}$ under the action of $\mathcal{F}_p$